# Delete multiple branches in using magit from `helm-mode-magit-branch-delete`

Tags: helm, magit, git

From the `magit-status` buffer, if I hit `b k` it will bring up a list of branches with `helm-mode-magit-branch-delete`. If I select a branch and hit `RET`, it will delete that branch (sometimes prompting to make sure that is what I want to do if the branch is unmerged).

**What I am looking for is a way to delete *multiple* branches.**

The documentation from `magit-branch-delete` says

> Delete one or multiple branches.
>   If the region marks multiple branches, then offer to delete
>   those, otherwise prompt for a single branch to be deleted,
>   defaulting to the branch at point.

However, from `helm-mode-magit-branch-delete`, I am not sure how to select multiple branches. I have tried using `C-SPC` (`helm-toggle-visual-mark`), which *visually* marks the branches I wan't, but when I hit `RET` with multiple branches marked, it only deletes the branch at point. I can't seem to find documentation for `helm-mode-magit-branch-delete`, and am out of ideas as to how to delete multiple branches. Any suggestions?

Also, as suggested in the comments below, I am not sure that`helm-mode-magit-branch-delete` is an actual command since I can't find it documented or referenced anywhere else, but it is the name of the buffer when I try to call `magit-delete-branch` from the `magit-status-buffer`, so this was the only way I new to reference it. From my modeline:

[image]

Comment: I cannot even find the definition of `helm-mode-magit-branch-delete`. Are you sure such a command really exists? In what package is it defined?

Comment: @tarsius I also couldn't find documentation for this "command" or find where the interactions between `helm` and `magit` are defined, but `helm` seems to have taken over many of my `magit` commands - basically anywhere where something needs to be selected from a list, `helm` takes over.

Comment: I think that's the name of the buffer with the completion candidates, not the name of the function used populate that buffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The doc-string you quote talks about marking multiple branches in a *Magit buffer*, not during Helm completion.

You can show a buffer which lists all branches and tags using <kbd>y</kbd>. In that buffer you can mark multiple branches using the region. Then press <kbd>k</kbd> to delete them. You'll be asked if you really want to do so.

Magit does not support marking non-consecutive sections dired-style.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, and I appreciate being asked for confirmation even when branches have been merged, because the previous method I was using would not offer such confirmation. I have no problem selecting multiple branches this way using the region as you suggested, but is there by any chance a way to mark multiple non-consecutive branches? I have tried a few things and looked at the documentation, and it doesn't seem like I can do that, but I thought if anyone would know you would! : )

Comment: No, that's not supported.